# Can you get a 'handle' from a pointer?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to recreate the posix functionality of first reserving memory, then committing and then finally freeing (using mmap, mprotect and munmap). On Windows I think the closest equivalent is:

```
mmap     -> CreateFileMapping
mprotect -> MapViewOfFile
munmap   -> UnmapViewOfFile + CloseHandle
```

On posix, you only have the pointer, there is no 'handle' that needs to be closed. For reasons I don't want to get into, it would be much nicer if I didn't have to store these handles in addition to the pointers on windows also. Is there some way to achieve this on windows? For example, a call for 'what handle corresponds to this pointer', so I could recover it when I need to free?

My plan B is to store the handle at the base of each allocated memory page, but this has other drawbacks.

Comment: Mmap commits, not merely reserves. mmap = CreateFileMapping + MapViewOfFile + CloseHandle(mapping), mprotect = VirtualProtect, munmap = UnmapViewOfFile. If you close the mapping handle immediately after mapping the view, that avoids having to remember the handle to close later.

Comment: @RaymondChen I use mmap with PROT_NONE to reserve very large contiguous memory ranges, so I can dynamically commit more pages as needed. But anyway, I will try your suggestion, it sounds like it solves my issue!

Comment: @RaymondChen Respect! That should be converted to an asnwer.

Comment: If you just want to reserve memory and then commit it later, why not just use `VirtualAlloc` instead of `CreateFileMapping`+`MapViewOfFile`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau If you don't know how much contiguous space you need, you can reserve a large range, like 100gb and only actually commit as needed.

Comment: You can't VirtualProtect a region allocated with MapViewOfFile. The mapping owns the protection. (Similarly, you cannot MapViewOfFile with PROT_NONE.) It sounds like `mmap` is being overloaded for two different things: (1) I want to memory-map a file, and (2) I want to manipulate my address space on a page-by-page basis. Windows uses two different API families for these concepts. (1) is MapViewOfFile. (2) is VirtualAlloc.